# use .net dll in electron

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, electron

I am a .NET developer and new to `electron` and `node.js`.

From my `electron` application, I need to call one function inside a .NET class library DLL which will generate some document and will send to print.

I need to use this `electron` application only on the windows machine. I see plugin `Edge.js`, but am not sure this will work for me and also don't know how to include in my project.

Comment: http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/19 this slide might have info you need.

Answer (score 6):

**Edge.js** will do the trick.

See the following snippet:

```js
    var edge = remote.require('electron-edge');

    var toErMahGerd = edge.func({
         assemblyFile: 'ERMAHGERD.dll',
         typeName: 'ERMAHGERD.Translate',
         methodName: "ToErMahGerd"
    });
    
    document.getElementById("translate-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) { 
         var inputText = document.getElementById("input-text").value;
    
         toErMahGerd(inputText, function (error, result) {
              document.getElementById("output-text").innerHTML = result; 
         }); 
    });
```

And here is the [GitHub-repo](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) with not only good docs to dive in but a simple getting started.

Comment: That tutorial link is dead

Comment: @Liam: sorry I don't know where the tutorial is gone. I removed the link.